# Random lines during screen recording playback

Tags: video, video-encoding, video-editing, screencasting

Every time I record or screencast my desktop, once I play it back I get random lines appearing now and then, no matter what media player I use. They're either black or they show fragments of my desktop underneath. I used all the most famous programs out there, including:

- Kazam
- OBS Studio
- SimpleScreenRecorder

and others, but always with the same lousy result. Any idea on how to fix this annoying problem? I'm adding my linux-box software-hardware data below with 'inxi'

System:    Host: TheBigX Kernel: 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.10 wm: muffin 
           dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: B85M-DS3H-A v: x.x serial: N/A BIOS: American Megatrends v: F1 date: 01/19/2015 
CPU:       Quad Core: Intel Core i7-4790 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell speed: 2467 MHz min/max: 800/4000 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 430.26 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           chip ID: 10de:1401 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nvidia resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 960/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.26 direct render: Yes 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Gigabyte driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI 
           port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 113.97 GiB (12.2%) 
Info:      Processes: 261 Uptime: 1h 22m Memory: 15.63 GiB used: 2.06 GiB (13.2%) Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 7.4.0 alt: 7 Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.27

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Regards

Saverio

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently I was able to fix the issue, which was caused by the nvidia driver (what a surprise). After upgrading to Linux Mint 19.1 and after installing the latest nvidia driver, all I had to do was to open the nvidia-settings control panel, click on the 'Open GL settings' section and disable both 'sync to VBlank' AND 'Allow Flipping'.
That did, for me at least.